# python 3.7 - tkinter - create_image not displaying image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I try to display an image in a tkinter canvas

the oval shows up, the rectangle too

but not the image

```
cwd=os.getcwd()
canvas.TKCanvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100)   
canvas.TKCanvas.create_rectangle(0,0,20,20)
filename=r""+cwd+"/icons.png"
img = tk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
canvas.TKCanvas.create_image((5,5), image=img, anchor='nw')
```

I checked the file path... "icons.png" is there (it used to give errors until I fixed the path)

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: I noticed, depending on the place where the code was put, the image was there or not

Comment: omg...it gets garbage collected ....how can I get rid of this ? like use wxwidgets instead of tkinter ?